# ubuntu 22.04 LTS right audio channel not working

Tags: 22.04

Esteemed Linux Wizards,

Have a persistent audio problem (rebooting or restarting pulse audio doesn't work) in which the right audio channel isn't working in Ubuntu. My Linux skills are limited but I have eliminated the physical connections as the source of the problem. I'm passing my audio through my monitor (AOC CU34G3S 34") to my speakers over a display port connection from my PC running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have multiple computers hooked up to the Monitor and both audio channels work fine over HDMI and windows 11 on my laptop. Would appreciate any help you have to offer.